# javascript getElementById gives error in chrome but works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Here is My Javascript function :

```
function deleteAlert(tabstate){
    var form = window.document.alertsForm;
    var numOfElements = form.elements.length;
    var okDelete = "false";
    for (i=0; i < numOfElements; i++)
    {
        if(form.elements[i].checked)
        {
            okDelete = "true";
            break;
        }else{
            okDelete = "false";

        }

    }
    if(okDelete == "true")
    {
        //changPage("Screen1b.html");  only for prototype
        form.action="/cpi/producer/myAlerts/alertsGateway?jadeAction=MA06&tab="+tabstate;
        form.document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton').disabled=true;
        form.submit();

    }else{
        alert("Please select one or more items to delete.");
    }
}
```

I 'm calling this function in two jsps , the code snippet is same for both (note the same id values)

```
<input type=button value="Delete" id="deleteAlertsButton" title="Delete" class=fbutton onclick="javascript:deleteAlert('<%=state %>');">
```

now this works perfect for both jsp in IE8 but in chrome , it gives an error for second jsp :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Please help.

Comment: I think your reference to form.document is incorrect.  "document" is outside the form.

Comment: Why not use window.document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton')...

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with your use of Boolean values as strings. The Boolean value `true` isn't the same as string value `"true"`; likewise `false` doesn't equal `"false"`. You're also using loose equality operators `==` for comparison, but you should be using strict identity operators `===` instead. This could lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference to form.document is incorrect. "document" is outside the form

So change:

```
form.document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton').disabled=true;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton').disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
form.document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton').disabled=true;
```

try

```
document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton').disabled=true;
```

Comment: but the same javascript function works for other jsp.

Answer (score 0):

what is method of **alertsForm**?

Try change just document.getElementById() like this one

```
document.getElementById('deleteAlertsButton').disabled=true;
```

[Definition and Usage](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)